# python rounding error when sampling variable Y as a function of X with histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to sample a variable (SST) as a function of another variable (TCWV) using the function histogram, with weights set to the sample variable like this:

```
# average sst over bins
num, _   = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins)
sstsum, _ = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins,weights=sst)
out=np.zeros_like(sstsum)
out[:]=np.nan
sstav  = np.divide(sstsum,num,out=out, where=num>100)
```

The whole code for reproducability is given below. My problem is that when I plot a scatter plot of the raw data and then I plot my calculated averages, the averages lie way outside the data "cloud" like this (see points on right):

[image]

I can't think why this is happening, unless it is a rounding error perhaps?

This is my whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# if you have a recent netcdf libraries you can access it directly here 
url = ('http://clima-dods.ictp.it/Users/tompkins/CRM/data/WRF_1min_mem3_grid4.nc#mode=bytes')
ds=Dataset(url)

### otherwise need to download, and use this:
###ifile="WRF_1min_mem3_grid4.nc"
###ds=Dataset(idir+ifile)


# axis bins
bins=np.linspace(40,80,21)

iran1,iran2=40,60

# can put in dict and loop 
sst=ds.variables["sst"][iran1:iran2+1,:,:]
tcwv=ds.variables["tcwv"][iran1:iran2+1,:,:]

# don't need to flatten, just tried it to see if helps (it doesn't)
sst=sst.flatten()
tcwv=tcwv.flatten()

# average sst over bins
num, _   = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins)
sstsum, _ = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins,weights=sst)
out=np.zeros_like(sstsum)
out[:]=np.nan
sstav  = np.divide(sstsum,num,out=out,where=num>100)

# bins centroids
avbins=(np.array(bins[1:])+np.array(bins[:-1]))/2

#plot
subsam=2
fig,(ax)=plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(tcwv.flatten()[::subsam],sst.flatten()[::subsam],s=0.05,marker=".")
plt.scatter(avbins,sstav,s=3,color="red")
plt.ylim(299,303)
plt.savefig("scatter.png")
```

Comment: I wonder if you increase the number of bins (avbins) how the averages will look like? (I meant plot more red points)

Comment: I made the bins 4 times smaller but it doesn't help unfortunately..  The points jump up and down, so I suspect it is a precision error (if I just take one timeslice it looks ok).  Python uses double precision by default though no?

Comment: I re-run your code and found that sstav has 13 from 20 values equal to -99. So If you drop the line plt.ylim(299,303) you will get a different image. https://ibb.co/NyjsTv0

Comment: that's just a "missing" value for any bins with zero or <100 sample.  I updated the code to use np.nan instead.  The averaging issue is not affected by that though (now with the nan you can remove the ylim statement and the plot points are still off).

Comment: okay I will check it again

Comment: The not nan values, I don't see anything suspicious:
num [  452  9930 47660 25571  1914   330   107]
sstsum [  136149.78  2990704.8  14350418.    7702032.     576816.      99480.
    32264.  ]
sstav [301.2163302  301.17872608 301.09983214 301.2018302  301.36677116
 301.45454545 301.53271028]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't think why this is happening, unless it is a rounding error perhaps?

It is in fact a rounding error.

Specifically, when you're calculating the sum of sst within each bin here:

```
sstsum, _ = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins,weights=sst)
```

The results come out wrong by 0.1% versus two alternate methods I tried for calculating the sum.

I have two ideas for ways to fix this.

#### Approach #1

The simplest fix is to do the calculation in more precision.

```
sstsum, _ = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins,weights=sst.astype('float64'))
```

Without this change, sst has a dtype of float32.

#### Approach #2

You might want to keep the calculation in 32-bit floats for performance reasons. They are somewhat faster than 64-bit floats. An alternate solution would be to subtract the mean before summing to improve numerical stability.

```
sst_mean = sst.mean()
num, _   = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins)
sstsum, _ = np.histogram(tcwv, bins=bins,weights=sst - sst_mean)
out=np.zeros_like(sstsum)
out[:]=np.nan
sstav  = np.divide(sstsum,num,out=out,where=num>100)
sstav += sst_mean
```

This subtracts the overall mean of sst from each data point, then adds it back at the end. Since floats have more precision around 0, this makes the calculation more precise.

#### Comparison

Here is a plot of what approach #1 looks like:

[image: plot of sst vs tcwv done in higher precision]

The plot of approach #2 looks the same. The two methods are equal within 1.32 * 10<sup>-5</sup> of each other.